# Sourcing GIS data from First World War (WW1)?

Tags: qgis, data, cartography, history

Simple question, but does anyone know where I can get some detailed (eg 1:10m scale) vector data from the First World War?

I've been through the archives here, but it seems the best sites for it have already closed.

Comment: Not that I knew about any such repositories, but what kind of data are you looking for? Frontlines? Old cadastral maps? Battle plans? and 1:10 is a really, realy big scale. Even a floor plan for common shed is at least 1:200...

Comment: You may want to consider also posting this at http://history.stackexchange.com/ - normally cross-posting is frowned upon but because History SE is in Beta this may be a case where it is OK - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234495/how-to-ask-the-same-question-on-different-sites/234497#234497

Comment: WW1 was a big conflict so to avoid this question being too broad I think you should focus it down to which theatre and battle(s) you are interested in.

Comment: This is a good starting point http://www.greatwar.co.uk/research/maps/british-army-ww1-trench-maps.htm

Comment: I just spent an interesting afternoon in the current WW1 exhibition in the German National History Museum in Berlin a few weeks ago. They had lots of historical maps, but they were all at least 1:1000, mostly 1:10.000 and up.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that I totally missed the letter "m" in "1:10m scale" up in the question... just ignore the second half of my first comment, please!

Comment: Sorry, I should've been clear. I'm looking for national boundaries in particular. Also, PolyGeo - I had no idea about the history.stackexchange.com site (I figured that as I was after GIS data this would be the best place to ask), but I'll have a look there & see what I can find.

Comment: I'm not sure if National Geographic provides any data, but they recently published this article: [How World War I Launched Mapmaking at National Geographic](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2014/07/140716-world-war-maps-history-cartography/).  Maybe they have created some digital data to go along with their archives.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [here](http://censusmosaic.org/web/data/historical-gis-files).  They seem to have a lot of shape files that might fit your description.  Though the European dataset is in 30 year increments.

Your best bet is probably going to have to be recreate it.  Wikipedia has some [WWI maps in PNG format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BlankMap-World-WWI.PNG).  As others have mentioned, there are plenty of sites with historical raster maps that you could digitize.